# How to make ffmpeg select custom input stream width and height

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, video-streaming, video-processing

ffmpeg provides the `-map` option so you can select a program or a stream depending of the quality of streams. But it is useful if you already know what program corresponds to a desired width.

If I do not know what program or stream number has the width 640 and height 360, how can I tell ffmpeg to select the program or stream that has the 640x360 because it default select the best stream.

Comment: `ffmpeg` selects the "best" stream by default. From [stream selection](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-selection) docs, "for video, it is the stream with the highest resolution". Do you want to simply select the video with the largest widthxheight?

Comment: My HLS sttrean has 4-5 programs eatch containing streams with different widthxheight. ffmpeg automaticaly select the best (big) widthxheight but I want it to select the program (stream) with the  640x360 stream resolution not the best resolution